# Can't trigger VS Code's setting "git.confirmEmptyCommits": false

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't figure out what the VS Code setting `"git.confirmEmptyCommits"` does. Whether `true` or `false`, I can't see any differences when trying to submit a commit with no files or with no message.

Is this setting still relevant?